# Delay ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, delay

I have an ajax call:

```
    $.get( "include/go.php?do", { action: "get_submodels_by_model" } )
    .done(function( data ) {alert(data);});
```

The response is still in proccess when I get the alert back.
I need to delay it for a couple of seconds.

Is this possible?

Comment: Uhm, no! When the alert fires, the ajax call has completed.

Comment: But it still needs time to proccess.

Comment: Define "the response is still in process."  If the callback is executed, that means the server has returned a response.  Is the *server* also doing something asynchronously?  If so, you might want to make it synchronous in this case.  Either that or poll the server for the result of the process or perhaps use web sockets to receive the response when the server's state has updated.

Comment: *"The response is still in proccess when I get the alert back."* that isn't possible.

Comment: so put all your processing in `.done()` callback

Comment: I think that you should read a little more about asynchronous programming model before actually getting into AJAX.

Comment: I'll expalin - i'm fetching a page from a url with php, then performing actions on it using jquery. The callback only returns the php part, without the jquery part that operates on it.